# SQL: Uniqueness constraints and cycling rows

Tags: sql, transactions, unique-constraint

I am writing a library that (with the help of an ORM) will allow people to store rows that contain a `position` column, and move rows from one position to another at a later time. The idea is thus to allow users to re-order the stored pieces of data.

In a simple implementation, it would be enough to just make this an integer column, and to perform two UPDATE statements: One moving the desired row from its old position to its new position, and a second one moving shifting all rows in-between one position up/down (depending on the direction of movement).
However, this goes wrong when multiple of these query-pairs are happening at the same time, even if they are wrapped in TRANSACTIONs, because most of the time the transaction isolation level is not set to 'Serializeable', and therefore in those cases, two rows will end up with the same `position` values.

An idea to solve this was to use a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, but this would mean that we need to do both of above steps in a single UPDATE query. This is possible, using a modulo operation (something like `position = (((position - beginning) + 1) % length + beginning)`).

However, turns out that neither Postgres, nor MySQL nor SQLite is able to figure out that after the UPDATE statement the constraint would still hold. Instead, (for efficiency, or simplicity of implementation reasons?) they report an error as soon as you try to increment the first row to an already-existing position.

One 'solution' that someone mentioned to me, was to alter the constraint to become DEFERRED, which would mean that it would only be checked at the end of the transaction. However, I don't believe that this is widely supported across SQL databases (and I'd rather like for the library to work in a database-agnostic way).

Are there other options to ensure database integrity for this problem?

Comment: You can do the update in two steps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please elaborate! :D

Comment: For Postgres you can use a deferrable constraint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325977/330315 They are supported by Oracle, Postgres, SQLite and Apache Derby.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! This approach was already mentioned in my question, but I believe SQLite does not support them for UNIQUE constraints, and of course MySQL does not.

Comment: Perhaps Gordon was thinking something like: Suppose you have 1,2,3 moving to 3,1,2. Step 1: 1 => -3, 2 => -1, 3 => -2. Step 2: -1 => 1, -2 => 2, -3 => 3.

Comment: Given that this may not be mission critical, you may want to reconsider using a database constraint to enforce this. Just always pull them out with ORDER BY and fix any bugs that you may find (which you would have to do in case you have the db constraint, but with a db constraint it will fail immediately not letting the user overwrite their previous state)